# Lazy load of button background

Tags: java, android

To resume, I made an app with buttons and their backgrounds. I want to know if there's a way to lazy load these button backgrounds... I searched and I found that we can use Picasso, Universal image, or Asynctask but for `ImageView` and not buttons.

I tried something like this but I'm sure that it's not correct:

```
Picasso.get()
    .load(R.drawable.blue_xml_popcorn)
    .into((Target) BteyoutubePlay_popcorn);
```

So if somebody has a solution, it will be really helpful. :)

Thanks!